# Rellenar una lista desde la base de datos

Tags: arraylist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Al tratar de llenar la lista me llena las posiciones de forma incorrecta, es decir para tres registros empieza a llenar en la posición 0 el registro de forma correcta pero cuando pasa al segundo registro de alguna manera se borra el registro en la posición 0 y queda el registro repetido reemplaza en la posición anterior el registro si

```
 public  List<Alumno> listarAlumnos() 
{
    Alumno alu=new Alumno(); 
    List<Alumno> lista=new ArrayList<Alumno>();
    try 
    {
     conex= Conexion.conectar();
     pst=conex.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Alumnos");

     ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();

        while(res.next())
                    {
            //existe=true;
                        alu.setNro_carnet(res.getInt("Nro_carnet"));
                        alu.setNombres(res.getString("Nombres"));
                        alu.setApellidos(res.getString("Apellidos"));
                        alu.setEdad(res.getString("Edad"));
                        alu.setTelefono(res.getString("Telefono"));


              lista.add(alu);

         }

    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
       System.out.println("ERROR "+e.getMessage()); 
    }


   return lista; 
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intenta colocando la instancia del Alumno dentro del while

Comment: Gracias @Daniel funciono no entiendo porque no funciona conla instancia fuera del while

Comment: Porque estabas modificando un objeto que ya existía, cuando instancias un objeto se le asigna una posición en memoria y cuando lo agregas a la lista lo que hace es crear una referencia a esa posición en memoria, de esa forma es más óptimo el funcionamiento, pero en tu caso se podría decir que estabas modificando el elemento que ya tenías en el listado una y otra vez